# Xbox Live concern about switching xbox's and having the level of your rank change to the 1st level

Tags: xbox-network

I just Bought a new Xbox live card, And i'm going to get a new xbox in February. I am at level 39 in Black Ops and was wondering if i will be on the same level when i get my new xbox.

Answer (score 2):

Everything relating to your online gamer profile, such as gamer score, achievements, and progress in Xbox-live multiplayer modes, will carry over.  You will have to migrate your Xbox live account, which can be done simply by logging in with your current credentials on the new Xbox.

Single player progress and saved games, however, are another story.

Comment: not impossible to move them, this could be a help http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9435/transferring-all-dlc-to-new-xbox-360-download-all

Comment: @Andy I didn't say impossible; I just meant not automatic.

Comment: yah, i wished i phrased that better, but comments seem to have a no edit option.  i just wanted to show how it was doable without the need of answering (because it was not his question and it was you that mentioned it.)  sorry for the way it sounds.